# Unselect Radiobutton

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-selected-items

I can not remove the selection from radio buttons[image: Radio Buttons and Formula]

As shown in the image, I tried the following :
Patch(GUAT, ThisItem, {Radio: Blank()}); UpdateContext({lclResetRadios:true})

as stated here:
https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Power-Apps/Reset-and-deselect-radio-buttons/td-p/668512

but it did not work

Answer (score 0):

What I did was put a blank label around the button control (be careful not to cover the actual button where the user click to select the radio button, but outside that area), and used reset(radiobuttonname). Works beautifully. The user clicks the button and anywhere else outside the area it will deselect. Regards!